# Magento 2.4.3 - Products are not showing in the catalog page after we import a database from Magento 2.3 site

Tags: magento2

we have a fresh build of Magento 2.4.3 which when we sync products from an api call works fine and the products display correctly but we want to import the database and products from an existing Magento 2.3.4 site. When we import the database the products are not showing on the catalog pages. The products are shown in the backend in the products listing and also under the categories tree and in products in category in the category page. Going directly to the products url key displays the product and show the breadcrumb for it's categories but none of the catalog listings show any products. The search pages return no results as well

we have checked the setting for elastic search in the core_config_data table and they seem correct and we have tried reindexing but the products still don't show. Any one any ideas as we are at a loss at what to try now.

Comment: Are you using the proper Elasticsearch version for a 2.4? No errors or notices at all in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can check for errors in var/log. If you share specific errors in these files, the problem will be easier to solve.

Comment: errors in exception  log below

Comment: [2021-12-20 10:28:37] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [wp11-243_product_1]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"wp11-243_product_1","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"wp11-243_product_1"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index [wp11-243_product_1]","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"wp11-243_product_1","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"wp11-243_product_1"},"status":404} {"exception":"[object] (Elasticsearch\\Common\\Exceptions\\Missing404Exception(code: 404):

Comment: [2021-12-20 10:25:53] main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [priority] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"c0f1S-OzT7G5XXWIaVWHfA","index":"wp11243_product_1_v10"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"wp11243_product_1_v10","node":"udxgnXzoQS2zx3Mky1sO8w","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [priority] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"c0f1S-OzT7G5XXWIaVWHfA","index":"wp11243_product_1_v10"}}]}

Comment: This problem comes from Elasticsearch. You should double-check the Elasticsearch configurations in your project, maybe it's not working right now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Magento falls back to use ES6 but your version needs ES7.

```
php bin/magento config:set  catalog/search/engine  elasticsearch7
php bin/magento cache:clean config
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```